# shared library locations for matlab mex files:

Tags: gcc, matlab, mex, hdf5, rpath

I am trying to write a matlab mex function which uses libhdf5; My Linux install provides libhdf5-1.8 shared libraries and headers. However, my version of Matlab, r2007b, provides a libhdf5.so from the 1.6 release. (Matlab `.mat` files bootstrap hdf5, evidently). When I compile the mex, it segfaults in Matlab. If I downgrade my version of libhdf5 to 1.6 (not a long-term option), the code compiles and runs fine.

question: how do I solve this problem? how do I tell the mex compilation process to link against /usr/lib64/libhdf5.so.6 instead of /opt/matlab/bin/glnxa64/libhdf5.so.0 ? When I try to do this using `-Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib64` in my compilation, I get errors like:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.0, needed by /opt/matlab/matlab75/bin/glnxa64/libmat.so, may conflict with libhdf5.so.6
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of 'hdf5_read_strings.mexa64' failed.

make: *** [hdf5_read_strings.mexa64] Error 1
```

ack. the last resort would be to download a local copy of the hdf5-1.6.5 headers and be done with it, but this is not future proof (a Matlab version upgrade is in my future.). any ideas?

EDIT: per Ramashalanka's excellent suggestions, I

A) called `mex -v` to get the 3 `gcc` commands; the last is the linker command;

B) called that linker command with a `-v` to get the `collect` command;

C) called that `collect2 -v -t` and the rest of the flags.

The relevant parts of my output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/crti.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/crtbeginS.o
hdf5_read_strings.o
mexversion.o
-lmx (/opt/matlab/matlab75/bin/glnxa64/libmx.so)
-lmex (/opt/matlab/matlab75/bin/glnxa64/libmex.so)
-lhdf5 (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/libhdf5.so)
/lib64/libz.so
-lm (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/libm.so)
-lstdc++ (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/libstdc++.so)
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/libgcc_s.so)
/lib64/libpthread.so.0
/lib64/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/libgcc_s.so)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/crtendS.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

So, in fact the `libhdf5.so` from `/usr/lib64` is being referenced. However, this is being overriden, I believe, by the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which my version of Matlab automagically sets at run-time so it can locate its own versions of e.g. `libmex.so`, etc.

I am thinking that the `crt_file.c` example works either b/c it does not use the functions I am using (`H5DOpen`, which had a signature change in the move from 1.6 to 1.8 (yes, I am using `-DH5_USE_16_API`)), or, less likely, b/c it does not hit the parts of Matlab internals that need hdf5. ack.

Comment: In your output I see `lib64/libhdf5.so` which is a dynamic library. You need to specify the explicit path for the static library (with a .o suffix) and not use `-lhdf5`. Then post new linker output if it's still not working. If the `.so` file is the only one in the listing then that is the only one included. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or any other path, such as in `-L` shouldn't matter if you don't have `-lhdf5` as an option and you specify the path to the static library explicitly (see below). I agree with your comments on `h5_crtfile.c`, but all the information we need is in your linker output above.

Comment: I don't have a `libhdf5.o` file; gentoo's hdf5 package provides `libhdf5.so`, `libhdf5.a`, `libhdf5.la`, and some fortran and cpp files. Do I have to compile libhdf5 myself? this is an option...

Comment: Sorry, I meant `.a`, not `.o`. You can check that the `libhdf5.a` file you have is the correct version by e.g. `strings libhdf5.a`. I see `HDF5 Version: 1.8.4` in mine. If you can't get the right static library as a binary, it is easy to compile. See my comments to your other query below.

Comment: `strings /usr/lib64/libhdf5.a | grep 'library version'` gives the output

"HDF5 library version: 1.8.4
HDF5 library version: 1.8.4
..."
I'm just unable to link against the static library for some reason. the same warning about `-fPIC`

Comment: OK. I found the same `undefined reference to 'main'` error you get if I turn off `-bundle`. So, you need the equivalent of `-bundle` on your system when you call mex. From the manual it seems `-fPIC` (or `-fpic`) as a `CFLAG` and (perhaps) `-shared` as an `LDFLAG`. Yes, your header and library *do* seem to be the correct version. I doubt that you need to recompile `hdf5`with `-fPIC`, since it all works fine on my system with `-bundle`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following worked on my system:

1. Install hdf5 version 1.8.4 (you've already done this: I installed the source and compiled to ensure it is compatible with my system, that I get gcc versions and that I get the static libraries - e.g. the binaries offered for my system are `icc` specific).
2. Make a target file. You already have your own file. I used the simple `h5_crtfile.c` from [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/examples/C/h5_crtfile.c) (a good idea to start with this simple file first a look for warnings). I changed `main` to `mexFunction` with the usual args and included `mex.h`.
3. Specify the *static* 1.8.4 library you want to load explicitly (the full path with no -L for it necessary) and don't include `-lhdf5` in the `LDFLAGS`. Include a `-t` option so you can ensure that there is no dynamic hdf5 library being loaded. You also need `-lz`, with `zlib` installed. For darwin we also need a `-bundle` in `LDFLAGS`:

   ```
   mex CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/hdf5/include' LDFLAGS='-t /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a -lz -bundle' h5_crtfile.c -v
   ```

   For linux, you need an equivalent position-independent call, e.g. `fPIC` and maybe `-shared`, but I don't have a linux system with a matlab license, so I can't check:

   ```
   mex CFLAGS='-fPIC -I/usr/local/hdf5/include' LDFLAGS='-t /usr/local/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.a -lz -shared' h5_crtfile.c -v
   ```
4. Run the `h5_crtfile` mex file. This runs without problems on my machine. It just does a H5Fcreate and H5Fclose to create "file.h5" in the current directory, and when I call `file file.h5` I get `file.h5: Hierarchical Data Format (version 5) data`.

Note that if I include a `-lhdf5` above in step 3, then matlab aborts when I try to run the executable (because it then uses matlab's dynamic libraries which for me are version 1.6.5), so this is definitely solving the problem on my system.

Thanks for the question. My solution above is definitely much easier for me than what I was doing before. Hopefully the above works for you.

Comment: hmmm. when I try this, the compilation fails b/c `libmat.so` relies on `libhdf5.so`.  something strange there. unfortunately, I cannot include `mex.h` without also pulling in Mathworks' hdf5; regrettably, the header files distributed by Mathworks does not include `hdf5.h`.

Comment: OK, I've rewritten the post, see how that goes.

Comment: I compile in shell with gcc commands spit out by mex. So I tried your solution, skipping steps 2 & 3; (`-bundle` is Darwin-specific, BTW) using `h5_crtfile.c`, I get "Warning! The HDF5 header files included by this application do not match the
version used by the HDF5 library to which this application is linked. Data
corruption or segmentation faults may occur if the application continues.
'HDF5_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK' environment variable set, application will
continue.
Headers are 1.8.4, library is 1.6.5"
however, `file.h5` is created! BUT, with this trick on my mex, it still segfaults.

Comment: That's useful information: I didn't get any warnings with the h5_crtfile.c and the warning is very clear. So, on your system it must be finding a 1.6.5 version of the library somewhere. When you do the link (i.e. the third gcc call "spit out by mex"), do it with a -v and have a look in the "Library search paths" that reveals for another libhdf5*. Make sure there are *no* dynamic hdf5 libraries in the path (e.g. why did you skip step 2?), or matlab will take it's own (1.6.5) dynamic library when running. You are sure that the *static* libraries you're trying to link to are 1.8.4, right?

Comment: the text "Warning! The HDF5 headers, etc." does not appear in the *Matlab* window, rather it appears in the shell from which Matlab was called. (I think it is piped to stderr, actually). this may be why you are not seeing it? still working on this, per your suggestions...

Comment: Whether I do mex in matlab, gcc in matlab with !gcc or gcc in terminal, I don't get any warnings. If you use the -t option above, you'll see exactly what it is linking to. There must be an hdf5 dynamic library or a static library of the wrong version in the list produced by -t on your system.

Comment: my bad, the warning is when I call the function for the first time, not from `gcc`.

Comment: In any case, you must be linking to an hdf5 dynamic library or a static library of the wrong version. The -t option discussed above will tell you all about it. I've also found a simpler method of getting it to work with -force_load, see my new initial list above.

Comment: it appears that `-force_load` is a Darwin specific option and/or part of gcc 4.5 (I am using 4.3.4); looking through the `ld` manpage and on google, I find the `-whole-archive` option; when using this in my build process, I get the error "/usr/lib64/libhdf5.a(H5.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib64/libhdf5.a(H5.o): could not read symbols: Bad value"

Comment: OK, I've removed the reference to `-force_load`. You shouldn't need `-whole-archive` either. See my simplified solution and my comments to your question above.

Comment: trying the following:
`/mex CFLAGS='-I/usr/include' LDFLAGS='-t /usr/lib64/libhdf5.a -lz' h5_crtfile.c`
results in the error
"...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/crtend.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: link errors found, deleting executable `h5_crtfile.mexa64'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: OK. Do `strings /usr/lib64/libhdf5.a` as discussed above to check the version. Also check the version of your header. In my version `hdf5.h` has no info, but `H5public.h` has `#define H5_VERS_INFO    "HDF5 library version: 1.8.4"`. If you have incompatible versions, it may be best to download and compile into a separate `/usr/local/hdf5` directory as I have and set your `-I` as I have above. The output above may be easier to read as `code` in your question (but you don't want community wikify yourself from too many edits as I have).

Comment: `grep VERS_INFO /usr/include/H5public.h` gives "#define H5_VERS_INFO    "HDF5 library version: 1.8.4""
so I think that's legit.

Answer (score 3):

I am accepting Ramashalanka's answer because it led me to the exact solution which I will post here for completeness only:

1. download the hdf5-1.6.5 library from the hdf5 website, and install the header files in a local directory;
2. tell mex to look for "hdf5.h" in this local directory, rather than in the standard location (e.g. `/usr/include`.)
3. tell mex to compile my code *and the shared object library provided by matlab*, and do *not* use the `-ldfh5` flag in `LDFLAGS`.

the command I used is, essentially:

```
/opt/matlab/matlab_default/bin/mex -v CC#gcc CXX#g++ CFLAGS#"-Wall -O3 -fPIC -I./hdf5_1.6.5/src -I/usr/include -I/opt/matlab/matlab_default/extern/include" CXXFLAGS#"-Wall -O3 -fPIC -I./hdf5_1.6.5/src -I/usr/include -I/opt/matlab/matlab_default/extern/include " -O -lmwblas -largeArrayDims -L/usr/lib64 hdf5_read_strings.c /opt/matlab/matlab_default/bin/glnxa64/libhdf5.so.0
```

this gets translated by mex into the commands:

```
gcc -c -I/opt/matlab/matlab75/extern/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Wall -O3 -fPIC -I./hdf5_1.6.5/src -I/usr/include -I/opt/matlab/matlab_default/extern/include -O -DNDEBUG hdf5_read_strings.c
gcc -c -I/opt/matlab/matlab75/extern/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -Wall -O3 -fPIC -I./hdf5_1.6.5/src -I/usr/include -I/opt/matlab/matlab_default/extern/include -O -DNDEBUG /opt/matlab/matlab75/extern/src/mexversion.c
gcc -O -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/opt/matlab/matlab75/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined -o hdf5_read_strings.mexa64  hdf5_read_strings.o mexversion.o  -lmwblas -L/usr/lib64 /opt/matlab/matlab_default/bin/glnxa64/libhdf5.so.0 -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/matlab/matlab_default/bin/glnxa64 -L/opt/matlab/matlab_default/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
```

this solution should work on all my various target machines and at least until I upgrade to matlab r2009a, which I believe uses hdf5-1.8. thanks for all the help, sorry for being so dense with this--I think I was overly-committed to using the packaged version of hdf5, rather than a local set of header files.

Note this would all have been trivial if Mathworks had provided a set of the header files with the Matlab distribution...

Comment: This is how I handled multithreaded mex files that needed to link boost-thread.  But there MUST be some way to get it to link to the system library instead of the one inside Matlab and avoid the segfaults that way.  Being stuck with whatever boost is inside Matlab is not very nice.

Comment: Regarding Ramashalanka's helpful suggestions, I can also say that with my boost-thread linking situation I had to do this workaround in Linux but not in Mac; in Mac it seems that the mex command does not link in the internal versions as it does in Linux.

Comment: Something like the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927568/compiling-c11-code-as-part-of-a-matlab-mex-file might work (although the question is for something somewhat different).  I'll report back if I get it working.