# OS X Lion, Matlab 2011a, Mex: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, matlab, gcc, mex

Hello Fellow Matlab/OS X Users,

I was wondering if you can help me out once again.
I got here a c-file (st.c, a Stockwell time-frequency analysis for MEG-Data) for Matlab which I should compile for my system (OS X Lion, Xcode 4.1.1).
It includes

```
#include <fftw3.h>
```

So I downloaded the newest Version from http://www.fftw.org/ and compiled it.
So far so good. But if I try to compile the c file

```
mex -st.c
```

I get the following error:

```
-> gcc-4.2 -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  "st.mexmaci64"  st.o  -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_fftw_destroy_plan", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_fftw_free", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_fftw_malloc", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_fftw_import_wisdom_from_file", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_fftw_plan_dft_1d", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_fftw_export_wisdom_to_file", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_fftw_execute", referenced from:
      _ist in st.o
      _st in st.o
  "_mexFunction", referenced from:
     -exported_symbol[s_list] command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "st.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

(I should say that compiling the c-file from the Matlab example (yprime.c) works without any problem.)
By googling I couldnt find to much, but there was someone suggesting the following:

> MATLAB needs to   link 64-bit (x86_64). You'll need to find a working
>   64-bit gfortran   compiler whose libraries are 64-bit and
>   ABI-compatible with Apple's gcc.

Here http://r.research.att.com/tools/ I found GNU Fortran 4.2.4 for Mac OS X 10.7.
But this didnt change anything, the error remains the same.

I guess the architecture is compiled in the wrong way, but I have no idea how to change that for Matlab/Xcode. If this is the case, could someone pls tell me how to do it ?

Thanks for your Help

Comment: It looks like you haven’t compiled FFTW for x86_64 or it is not being linked against your program. Can you check that?

Comment: I droped the fft3w.h & fft3w.f into the matlabroot/extern/include
If i take it out of there I get the following error-msg: `fftw3.h: No such file or directory`.
I am not very familiar with mex and gcc, which is the best way to check if it is compiled and linked in the right way ?

Comment: And I’m not familiar with neither FFTW nor Fortran nor MATLAB, heh. That said, it looks like when `mex` invokes `gcc` it’s not passing the FFTW library — at least I can’t identify it on that `gcc` line. Or maybe it is, but FFTW hasn’t bee compiled for x86_64. If you have a FFTW library (maybe with .o, .a, or .dylib extensions), run `lipo -info` against it and it’ll tell you the architectures for which it’s been compiled.

Comment: I found the libfftw3.a and it seems like the architecture is correct or ?
`Non-fat file: libfftw3.a is architecture: x86_64`

Comment: Great. So, as far as I can tell, you need to figure out how to tell `mex` that it should link that libfftw3.a file since it doesn’t show up in that `gcc` line. It should appear either as is or as `-lfftw3`.

Comment: @Irreducible: I think you need to specify where the compiler/linker should look for the header files and libraries: `mex prog.c -I/path/include -L/path/lib/ -lfftw`. You can check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f24338.html#f24347) [pages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mex.html) for complete details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against the fftw library. You can pass linker flags directly to the mex command. So you probably want to issue a command like:

```
>> mex -v -I/path/to/fftw/include -L/path/to/fftw/lib/ -lfftw3 st.c
```

The `-v` option will put `mex` into verbose mode and will print out the `gcc` commands used to compile and link the mex file. This output is helpful for debugging linking problems

Comment: Now I get that error:
`gcc-4.2 -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  "st.mexmaci64"  st.o  -L/usr/local/lib/ -lfftw3 -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mexFunction", referenced from:
     -exported_symbol[s_list] command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: I found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188658/shared-library-locations-for-matlab-mex-files) an answer which let me compile my c file:
`mex CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/lib' LDFLAGS='-t /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a -lz -bundle' st.c -v`