# How can one configure mex to pass compiler flags to nvcc

Tags: matlab, compilation, mex, nvcc

While compiling `mex` files with `nvcc` I have struggled to pass compiler options specific to CUDA to the `nvcc` compiler, as `mex` doesn't recognize them.

I found some [old posts about passing compiler flags](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93372-how-can-i-pass-the-gcc-framework-compiling-option-to-the-mex-compiler-on-mac-in-matlab-7-1-r14sp) and [some newer ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648949/error-when-compiling-c11-code-in-a-matlab-mex-file),
but the questions are quite user-specific, and the `mex` compiler has changed over the years, so I cant figure out what to do.

So, my specific question: What should I do to make `mex` pass compiler flags to `nvcc`?

A bit more generic: What should one do to make `mex` pass compiler flags to another compiler?

Comment: It's such a headache that I just do it in the [Visual Studio IDE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30408715/2778484) using the integration installed with the CUDA Toolkit.  But I'd like to add an answer to your question if I get time today.  In short, I usually use property sheets, where you can type additional flags, but again this uses the IDE to compile rather than `mex`.  Is that too specific of a use case?  Or the new way with an XML...

Comment: Or the new way with an XML [as I do for MinGW](https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/tree/master/MinGW).  Or is this not what you mean?

Comment: @chappjc if you have an answer add it,  at least for future lost compilers.

Comment: Yes, I figured you have _your_ answer.  :)  Just wanted to be on topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If working with the newest compiling way where the options are in an xml file, one can hardcode the default compile flags in there. For example mine looks like:

```
COMPILER="nvcc"
      COMPFLAGS="-gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode=arch=compute_50,code=&#92;&quot;sm_50,compute_50&#92;&quot; --compiler-options=/c,/GR,/W3,/EHs,/nologo,/MD"
      COMPDEFINES="--compiler-options=/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE,/D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE,/D_SECURE_SCL=0,$MATLABMEX"
      MATLABMEX="/DMATLAB_MEX_FILE"
      OPTIMFLAGS="--compiler-options=/O2,/Oy-,/DNDEBUG"
      INCLUDE="-I&quot;$MATLABROOT\extern\include&quot; -I&quot;$MATLABROOT\simulink\include&quot;"

  DEBUGFLAGS="--compiler-options=/Z7"
```

One can change the defaults modifiying `COMPFLAGS`

Comment: Where does one find this file? Is it generated automatically?

Comment: @Floris Good question, but vague answer (this is 5 years ago!). I found mine within MATLAB installation. There are few `xml` files there for visual studio compiling, and then I added these things to that. If you want a modified template that should work for CUDA, check my tool "TIGRE toolbox" in github, I provide various `xml` already set for CUDA.

Comment: Answering my own question... you can find the file in the `prefdir` directory - so `dir(fullfile(prefdir,'mex*.xml'))` should give you a pretty good idea of what's there.