# Unable to compile MEX

Tags: c++, c, matlab, compiler-errors, mex

I am trying to compile some MATLAB MEX files from C++ source. The files I am trying to compile [can be found here](http://sourceforge.net/p/oscmex/code/4/tree/trunk/src/); I am using Windows XP on a 32-bit system, MATLAB 2012a and have installed the Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1 to use as my compiler.

MATLAB outputs the following error if I try to compile:

```
>> mex -O -largeArrayDims osc_free_address.c
osc_free_address.c 
osc_free_address.c(1) : error C2059: syntax error : '<' 
osc_free_address.c(37) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(38) : error C2059: syntax error : '<' 
osc_free_address.c(39) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(39) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(39) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(41) : error C2018: unknown character '0x40' 
osc_free_address.c(43) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(44) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(44) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(44) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(44) : error C2015: too many characters in constant 
osc_free_address.c(46) : error C2059: syntax error : '<' 
osc_free_address.c(82) : fatal error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'page' 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'osc_free_address.c' failed. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

I have used *mex -setup* to setup my compiler with *Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1*. Interestingly, although I have them installed on my system, MATLAB doesn't see MS Visual Studio C++ 2008 **or** 2010. I have also tried compiling with the *Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1* compiler (which *is* recognised by MATLAB), to the same effect as shown above.

I understand that this particular set of C++ source files *might* require something called [liblo](http://plugin.org.uk/liblo/) to compile (I'm not sure whether this is a requirement at compile-time or run-time); as far as I'm aware I have installed these correctly, but there's a possibility that the problem might lie here too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming your `.c` files to `.cpp` and re-compile

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims -O osc_free_address.cpp
```

Moreover, why don't you try the build m file that comes with the package
(as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789656/linking-matlab-to-a-dll-library))?

Have you downloaded and compiled liblo? you might need to add the include path and library path for it in the `mex` command?

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims -O -I<liblo include path> -L<liblo lib path> -llo osc_free_address.cpp
```

Comment: This causes a similar (but longer) error message. As for using the 'osc_make.m' file, this doesn't appear to be a 'm' file at all; it contains HTML/CSS-like code. I have no idea what its purpose is; it throws an error on line #1 if I try to run it in MATLAB.

Comment: the [`osc_make`](http://sourceforge.net/p/oscmex/code/4/tree/trunk/src/osc_make.m#l32) is a valid matlab code. However, reading its comment it requires gnumex and mingw and some other per-requisites regarding liblo compilation without pthreads.

Comment: It seems that downloading the code from SourceForge provides a very different file to that obtained by opening the file and copying the contents!

Comment: @CaptainProg - you'll have to change the folder names in `ocs_make` to fit your folders. Have you managed to setup liblo?

Comment: Thanks for your help Shai. I've gotten all the paths correct, and I do have liblo on my system; whether or not it's correctly set up I don't know. I had to use Cygwin to 'make' liblo - to do this I copied the liblo folder into Cygwin's folder and used the Cygwin shell to run the 'make' command. After doing this, I moved the liblo folder to my MATLAB directory and have now pointed to this. I don't know whether the act of moving the liblo folder has broken anything; I simply didn't know how to go higher than the Cygwin dir when I was 'making' the liblo library. Any ideas?

Comment: it sounds like you need to use gnumex as suggested in the `osc_build` file. No way of building liblo with VS?

Comment: It seems I am now learning how to build a library so that I can build a library! I honestly have no idea whether it can be done with VS - the INSTALL file included in the liblo download speaks of the "simplest" way to install, and it involves a Unix shell.

Comment: @CaptainProg - don't forget you are supposed to comment out pthreads in liblo

Comment: The liblo source files contain 25 instances of the text 'pthread', in multiple files; many of these instances are in-line with other code. There would be a *lot* of scope for error if I go through and modify every instance. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: @CaptainProg I don't think you are missing anything. pthread is not supported on windows, you are walking a very sloppy path...

Comment: What is meant by 'comment out pthreads'? It would be impossible to comment it out without destroying other code...

Comment: @CaptainProg - I'm afraid this is an unfamiliar territory for me as well. As much as I would like to help you, I'm afraid you're on your won now... Good luck!